# nginx get subdomain of the url and assing the document root

Tags: php, regex, nginx

Im no expert on nginx but i got my problem solved by doing this:

```
server_name ~^(?<vhost>.*)$;
root /var/www/$vhost/public;
```

For example if a user types in a web browser http://sysadmin.mydomain.com nginx will use the doc root of **/var/www/sysadmin.mydomain.com/public**

And this works fine, but in doing so I have created another problem with PHP $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; and its that this will print: **~^(?.*)$** causing problems somewhere else in my code.

My solution works for nginx but its not the right solution. How can i achieve this and still retain a 'readable' server name?

Comment: You have different subdomains as distinct folders in `/var/www`, correct?  How many such subdomains you have?  I believe that (unless you have hundreds subdomains) you shall write separate `server` blocks for each subdomain.  That approach has several advantages.

Comment: @grochmal Correct, but have no control over those folders since they are dynamically created by my app. I will post an answer to this topic now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick for what I want:

```
server_name mydomain.com ~^(?<vhost>.+)\.mydomain\.com$;
root /var/www/$vhost.mydomain.com/public;
```

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will answer: mydomain.com and thats fine for what I want.

Comment: OK, i understand.  You only keep the `mydomain.com` part in the PHP code.  I just commented to argue whether `~^(?<vhost>[^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$` wouldn't be faster.  By adding `[^.]+` instead of `.+` the regex does not need to backtrack, (likely) resulting in a faster regex.